# Find all integers such that there is a number and all elements more than it can be written using the elements of a set in exactly that many ways.

Tags: number-theory

Find all integers $r$ such that $\exists$ $p \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}, A \subset \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and every $q > p$ can be written using distinct elements from $A$ in no more or less than $r$ ways.

I think it is not possible. But I could not generate an example for any number either. Can I get a few examples so I can verify it further?

Comment: Well, with $r=1$ you could just take $A$ to be the powers of $2$, for example.

Comment: @lulu You are right actually. I have a feeling that $A_{n} = \left(\cup_{k \geq 0} \{{p_1}^k\}\right) \cup \left(\cup_{k \geq 0} \{{p_2}^k\}\right) \cup \dots \cup \left(\cup_{k \geq 0} \{{p_n}^k\}\right)$ where $p_j$ is the $j$th prime, $p_1 = 2$.

Comment: @lulu The above [what I wrote] does not work.

Comment: With $r=1$ there is no problem. My example works, though you could also let $A$ be the powers of $3$ union twice the power of threes, and so on.  Taking $r>1$ seems hard...after all if $n,m$ can each be written in exactly two ways, it would seem likely that $n+m$ could be written in more than two ways.  Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @S.Dolan  Now I think I was wrong, though.  I think the powers of $2$ plus the number $3$ works for $r=2$.  Indeed, for any $n≥3$ we can write $n$ uniquely as a sum of distinct powers of $2$ and we can write $n-3$ uniquely as a sum of distinct powers of $2$.

Comment: @lulu Luckily our results don't contradict each other!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for $r=2$ (which might make the general pattern clear).  Let $$A=\{1,2,3,4,8,16, \cdots , 2^n, \cdots\}$$

That is, $A=\{2^n\}\cup \{3\}$.

In that case, of course, $1,2$ can only be written in one way.  But any greater number has one decomposition that uses $3$ and one which does not.

Comment: This idea  gives a solution for r any power of 2. (+1)

Comment: P.S. Your powers of $3$ idea doesn't work for $r=1$ because, for example, $9=9$ and $9=6+3$. Can you think of any example for any $r$ other than the one given in my deleted post?

Comment: @S.Dolan  Right about about the powers of $3$.  As you say, we can get powers of $2$ for $r$....at the moment I don't have any idea for any different $r$.